# Learning about composite resins, should the resin be able to adhere to the selected filler?

Tags: materials, composite-resin

I'm learning about composite resins, and the various filler additives, but I wondered about the relation between the two. For example....

An epoxy resin has poor adherence to a material such as polyethylene, but it has strong adherence to a material such as polyamide 66.  If you have an epoxy resin with powdered polyethylene, vs polyamide 66, beyond the characteristics of the powdered material itself, what impact does the resins ability to adhere to the powered filler have?

Comment: The effect can be very different depending on a number of parameters. E.g. are you using long fibers, short fibres of particulate filler?

Comment: @NMech does the ability to adhere to the filler material have more or less impact depending on the particle/fiber size/length?  Shortish fibers, and microfibers.

Comment: Generally composites with  longer fibers are more affected by the fiber matrix interface.  The smaller the reinforcement particulate size usually the effect from bad interface is less pronounced. However again that has to do with the properties of the matrix e.g energy for crack propagation in the bulk matrix material.

Comment: @NMech, make this an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally composites with longer fibers are more affected by the fiber matrix interface. The smaller the reinforcement particulate size usually the effect from bad interface is less pronounced. However again that has to do with the properties of the matrix e.g energy for crack propagation in the bulk matrix material.